# .htaccess redirect everything uknown except a few defined ones

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite `/home` to the `index.php` and `/edit` to `edit.php`, but everything else, like `/asdfg` I want to redirect to `new.php`

Both edit and home on their own work, but the `(.*)` takes priority over those rules, I tried it without the `RewriteCond`, but then nothing works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^edit$ /edit.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new.php [L,R=301]
```

I just need all undefined URI's to redirect to `/new.php`

I also need to keep the `/asdfg` in the URI, so I can grab it with JavaScript and show the appropriate content, an either show a page to let ppl make a new post or to show existing content.

I can't define all existing content, because that comes from a database, only a few predefined, reserved `"/folders"` will redirect to predefined pages.

I have the following working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [R]
RewriteRule ^edit$ /edit.php [R]
```

It leaves the /home there and go to index.php

Now I just need to redirect all unknown requests to a default page new.php.

I basically want to prevent users getting a 404 or any other error, ever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `last` flag to your first RewriteRules, so that the last RewriteRule does not take effect:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^edit$ edit.php [L]
```

Comment: That does it, however, now when I get directed to /new.php, it doesn't leave the /asdfg there... It puts /new.php there, but I need to keep the users input, to be able to grab it with javascript..

Comment: Try to remove the `R=301` from the last rule. This `R` flag forces a redirect, not a rewrite.

Comment: It's weird, I tried, but It still made it /new.php.. But it seems a browser cache issue.. It worked when I used another alias for my domain, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag to the "home" and "edit" rules, so that the "new" rule isn't processed once they're matched.